# How to set an emoji instead of hostname on Mac Terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, emoji

I've seen some people on the internet have emoji for their hostname which makes the terminal much more readable when you scroll up to see history.

I have tried Terminal -> Preferences -> Profile and looked at all the options, but there's no option for adding an emoji.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sudo scutil --set HostName pasteYourEmojiHere
```

For example:

```
sudo scutil --set HostName
```